# How do I link libgcc statically in rust

Tags: rust, static-linking, libgcc

I am trying to compile a Rust program with statically linked libgcc.

The program is meant to run in `initramfs` in a restricted environment and is compiled for different platforms (arm, x86_64).

Currently my only solution is to compile against musl which produces a statically linked binary.

Unfortunately this adds a bit of complexity to the build process - I have not found a way to cross-compile for arm-musl on x86 and I have extra installation requirements (musl-gcc).

I have tried to add this:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static", "-C", "link-args=-static-libgcc"]
```

...to `.cargo/config`, but as far as I understand `+crt-static` only works on Windows, and `-static-libgcc` showed no effect either.

Comment: You need a statically build libgcc in order for `-static-libgcc` to do anything if I remember correctly. Are you sure your cross-compiler actually provides a static version of libgcc? I believe it should be named `libgcc_s.a`